# Fetch method does not send content with post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

Bellow is part of code I wrote to log in to uni web application. When I make post with below parameters in Postman it allows me to log in and redirect me to profile page, but when I make post from my app nothing happens. I used Charles to check request and find out that content of request is empty. I found this parameters in browser (network monitor and source code) while logging in regularly trough web.

This method is taken from Postman, so I believe it should work in app as it works in Postman.

```
const loginHandler = () => {
   console.log("-----------------!!!-------------");
   var myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  
   var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
   urlencoded.append("__EVENTTARGET", " ");
   urlencoded.append("__EVENTARGUMENT", " ");
   urlencoded.append(
     "__VIEWSTATE",
     "stg"
   );
   urlencoded.append("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", " xxx");
   urlencoded.append(
     "__EVENTVALIDATION",
     " /something"
   );
   urlencoded.append("txtLogin", " username");
   urlencoded.append("txtPassword", " pass");
   urlencoded.append("btnLogin", " Login");

   var requestOptions = {
     method: "POST",
     headers: myHeaders,
     body: urlencoded,
     redirect: "follow",
   };

   fetch(
     "http://example/login.aspx",
     requestOptions 
   )
     .then((response) => response.text())
     .then((result) => console.log(result))
     .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
 };
```

Is it possible that body is not encoded properly?

Comment: You probably don't want to send a username and password without HTTPS... also, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restrictions might be preventing you from posting to another origin. I don't believe Postman has that limitation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts problem was with `URLSearchParams()` and headers, I had to change it to `FormData()` and delete headers for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
First problem was that Postman generated `fetch()` method which used `URLSearchParams()` interface for the body data and when I changed it to `FormData()` it started working as I wanted.
Second problem was, and I don't understand why, that when I changed to `FormData()` headers gave me an `error [TypeError: Network request failed]`, and when I commented them out everything was good again.

I didn't try to change `"Content-Type"` to something else and check does it work, but I will.